# How to make iPhone 4s with iOS6 beta a peripheral device?

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-bluetooth, peripherals

I want my iPhone 4s act as peripheral device. To do that I have used peripheral manager that included in iOS 6 beta but now my device is not discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the header for CBPeripheralManager and CBCentral. There are no docs currently available online, but there are a lot of comments in those headers. The usage model is very similar to CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral.